# How to read the cmd output as Input in C using System()

Tags: c

Is this possible to get the cmd output as input in C using `system()`?.
I want to read the output of the cmd as input.

For Ex.
The command in `system("echo %username%");` will result the current logged user name as output like `Prasanthvel`. I just want to read the output and store in a string to do some program.

Note : I don't want to save it into a text file, and this question is different from other questions in this forum or  the answers were not sufficient to do this.

Comment: read about `popen()`

Comment: Hi @Stargateur I Need to do it with `system()` function not with `popen()`

Comment: @some programmer dude. That answer was not sufficient to do this.

Comment: It's not possible with `system`, unless you want to redirect the output to a file that you later read. That's it. End of story. Full stop.